# Dropbox Syncronization Problem

Tags: 12.04, command-line, dependencies, dropbox

I am using 12.04 and tried Dropbox but faced the following problem.:

```
irtaza@irtaza-OptiPlex-990:~$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Follow http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-dropbox-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Answer (score 1):

To install Dropbox, you need to

1. Download the Ubuntu .deb file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install). Choose 32 or 64 bit depending on your system architecture.
2. Double click on the downloaded file and install it via the Ubuntu Software Centre.
3. Run *Dropbox* by  searching for it in the Dash. The first time it runs it should download some proprietary components.
4. You should then by able to install `nautilus-dropbox` with the original command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
   ```

#### Why is this necessary?

When you tried to install Nautilus Dropbox originally, that attempted to install the Dropbox icons for Nautilus, not Dropbox itself. It required the Dropbox program in order to do anything. Dropbox only releases it's program itself (not in the Ubuntu repos), so it was uninstallable with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting the dependencies with;

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```